# Convolution Formula to find PDF

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution

I need to use the formula
\begin{align*}
f_{Y_1}(y_1) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_{1}X_{2}}(y_1-y_2, y_2)d_{y_2}
\end{align*}

to find the pdf of $Y_1 = X_1 + X_2$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the joint pdf $f_{X_{1}X_{2}}(x_1, x_2) = 2e^{-(x_1+x_2)}$ for $0 < x_1 < x_2 < \infty$, zero elsewhere.

First, let $Y_2 = X_2$ so that $X_1 = Y_1-Y_2$ and $X_2 = Y_2$. Then, the bounds $0 < x_1 < x_2 < \infty$ become $0 < y_1-y_2 < y_2 < \infty$, or $y_2 < y_1 < 2y_2 < \infty$. Now using the formula and noting that $0 < y_2 < y_1$, I obtain

\begin{align*}
f_{Y_1}(y_1) = 2\int_{0}^{y_1}e^{-y_1}dy_2 = 2y_1e^{-y_1}.
\end{align*}

Basically, I am just unsure if my bounds for $y_2$ are correct. Are there any errors in my work? Thank you =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is $2\int_{\frac {y_1} 2}^{y_1} e^{-y_1}dy_2=y_1e^{-y_1}$. [I fact what you have obtained is not  density function since it does not integrate to $1$].

Comment: can you explain how you get the bounds $\frac{y_1}{2}$ to $y_1$?

Comment: @mXdX When you integrate w.r.t. $y_2$ keeping $y_1$ fixed you have to take into account all inequalities involving $y_2$. You forgot the in equality $y_1 <2y_2$ which says $y_2 >\frac {y_1} 2$.

Comment: ah, okay, so I should have realized from my inequality $y_2 < y_1 < 2y_2 < \infty$ that $y_2 < y_1$ and also $\frac{y_1}{2} < y_2$, I see.